# Reverse models relationship in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two schemas (Portfolio and Projects that relate to portfolios):

```
portfolioSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    isActive: {type: Boolean, default: true}
});

projectSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    isActive: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: true},
    portfolio: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'portfolioSchema', required: true},
    isCodeBaseFullyOwned: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false}
});
```

Is there a way to select all portfolios and 'populate' their relevant projects? I can group projects by portfolio but then if there are no projects in a portfolio I would have to figure a way to additionally pull this information, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you could do this.
One would be adding an array of projectIds on the portfolio which you could then populate but could become messy if you are not careful with cleaning up/managing references on updates.

This can be done by updating the portfolioSchema to

```
portfolioSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    isActive: {type: Boolean, default: true},
    projects: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'projectSchema', required: true}]
});
```

The other option would require grouping projects by portfolio as you have said and then collecting all portfolio ids that return, and running a second query to get portfolios with

```
{_id: {$nin: <array of already returned portfolio ids>}}
```

Both options have pros and cons but currently these are the only two options that I can think of.

Comment: I could probably write a little hook to smoothen these reverse-lookup routines but I found a suggestion to implement this in mongoose someone booked back in 2014, not sure why they haven't picked it up - it could be a very useful feature.

Comment: Agreed, there are a lot of features that would be nice to see in mongoDB.